# Scalding: How to change default tuple comparison function?

Tags: scala, scalding

Doing Scalding MapReduce operations I need to compare tuples using my own comparison function on tuple fields.

Questions:

1. How to define my own tuple comparison function?
2. What are the rules to extend Scalding with custome Scala code in general? Limitations?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific: what API are you using, what operations do you need -- sort, group, etc.?

Comment: There is only one API I know `com.twitter.scalding._` Please, let me know the other ones. I need my own tuple comparison functions for grouping and sorting. For example, sort by first 4 leading characters in `second name` field.

Comment: There is also typesafe API at com.twitter.scalding.typed. I am assuming you are using Field-based API (RichPipe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create virtual field (e.g. by using `com.twitter.scalding.RichPipe#map`), sort by this field and then take it away. Here is an example based on the [Scalding Documentation](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Fields-based-API-Reference#sortBy):

```
val users = Csv(file_source, separator = ",", fields = Schema)
  .read
  .map ('age-> 'ageInt) {x:Int => x}
  .groupAll { _.sortBy('ageInt) }  // will sort age as a number.
  .discard ('ageInt)
```

Comment: Is it possible instead of creating virtual field, just take some part of the existing field, such as: `groupAll { _.sortBy(takeFirstFourChars('secondName)) }` ?

Comment: Not sure you can do this: the .sortBy function takes a list of fields as a parameter. What is a problem with adding and then removing field?